# Appending JSON to a table using jquery always appends the data twice. Not sure how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I have this super odd issue here and I can't seem to get this to work properly. I am appending json data to a table but it keeps appending each line of data twice. I am hopeful someone here can see what I could possibly be doing wrong.

```js
   data = JSON.parse('[{"status":true,"user":{"username":"Chris","avatar":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/avatars\/iiPjqYlVkijUv9XoPt0YUpyHuueBdkFkrTjIwnJd.gif","rep":{"positive":1,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"JucpDM8","title":"Non-Full Access(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png","path":"product_images\/SDcaqvqginNTmVKwYHCDfajoOqc0OqHjq3pMjyAw.png"},"quantity":{"min":25,"max":1000000},"price":0.02,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":500,"type":"account","stock":12},{"id":"qX4vLC2","title":"Unmigrated(UFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg","path":"product_images\/F0PaLkMLbWS9gZt7DtRfMNYm2bufv796HTlm4gFe.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":5.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"sYu98Kq","title":"Semi-Full(SFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg","path":"product_images\/5mGCAH4Fsj23MlBHw5yw1UoPsw65dGI1ZkmxwNfN.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"7efhwnl","title":"Optifine Cape","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg","path":"product_images\/W6q61CMgmlzzwtQlk0jXfaXbOcse4YfhrHEIuF0N.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":2,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"kBkgLAv","title":"Hypixel Ranked(NFA)","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png","path":"product_images\/nxvFRT9YcKVuOHPilMGdLM08i7JhYTdd4Aqq0xSK.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":4.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":5,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"X5kmV3z","title":"Lamm","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg","path":"product_images\/rgGnCcqMIqgvsETsVTWjrF2EhVSwIOE5bXNwEtUC.jpeg"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.05,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"AFwEIkN","title":"Lammy","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png","path":"product_images\/mUbSzYsq8iII9Ro3wmJkyWRwk4oBVJmDNKavBGr4.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"JYcUni4","title":"Jess","image":{"url":"https:\/\/s3-storage.\/\/product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png","path":"product_images\/GaVbNGASgkv6LCErOjg1zK9MFWlrySvZGUVNCjPb.png"},"quantity":{"max":1000000,"min":5},"price":0.5,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":10,"type":"account","stock":14}],"groups":[{"id":"4TlYivf","title":"Minecraft Is","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["sYu98Kq","JucpDM8","qX4vLC2","7efhwnl","kBkgLAv"]},{"id":"GTXwlkU","title":"Streaming","image":"","unlisted":false,"products":["JYcUni4","AFwEIkN","X5kmV3z"]}],"feedbacks":[{"updated_at":"2018-09-16 00:29:35","stars":5,"rating":1,"comment":"The best thing in the world! Thanks!","response":"Thank you so much! Come again!","product":null}],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"bear","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"p9YymiV","title":"fortnite","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":75,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}},{"status":true,"user":{"username":"king","avatar":"\/images\/default-avatar.png?id=55b864e42ffc120971da","rep":{"positive":0,"neutral":0,"negative":0},"products":[{"id":"91vFhN4","title":"uplay","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":4,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":0},{"id":"vX5IJ4T","title":"premium","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":2,"currency":"EUR","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854775807}],"groups":[],"feedbacks":[],"online":{"state":false,"ago":"1 year ago"},"staff":false}}]');

$.each(data, function(_, v1) {
  $.each(v1.user.products, function(_, v2) {
    $.each(v2.image, function(_, v3) {
      $(".table").append($("<tr>").append(
        $("<img>").css({
          width: 60
        }).attr("src", v2.image.url),
        $("<td>").addClass("Title").text(v2.title),
        $("<td>").addClass("Price").text("$" + v2.price),
        $("<td>").addClass("Stock").text(v2.stock),
        $("<td>").addClass("Link").append(
          $('<a target="_blank">').attr("href", "https://shop.link/product/" + v2.id + "/")
          .text("Buy Now"))
      ));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<title>Test Check</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Stock</td>
        <td>Link</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I assume this is some error with my JQuery and not my html but I have exhausted all my options here that I am aware of. I feel like it might have something to do with `"table").append($("<tr>").append(`. Almost like its creating a double table. I have tried clearing the table before running the append script with same results, as well as checking all my tags are closed properly. My brain must not be working right tonight. Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Could you provide the contents of `test.json` too?

Comment: Sure, I totally forgot. I updated the original post. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You’re appending the `<tr>` to the div, not the `<table>`?

Comment: What is your intended functionality with the image if it doesn't exist? Do you want to show that row still (just without an image) or do you want to skip that row completely? Right now you're iterating over each property of `image` in the JSON which is why it's outputting each one twice. So you can comment out that third `$.each` and then just check if `image == ''` if you want to output it or not.

Comment: Ahhh, I see the issue why my loop would break now. I would ideally use a placeholder but I haven't gotten that far. But I still want the line to stay. I was wondering why adding the third loop to get the image URL would fix my looping issue but break the functionality by double posting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `$('<td>')` do compared to `$('td')`? This may just be a syntax that I'm unfamiliar with. As a test, on this site (jQuery v1.12.4) when I run `$('<a>').length` I get `1`, but when I run `$('a').length` I get `304`.

Answer (score 1):

You append data twice because your third each loop loops through image which have two values: path and link. So just don't do it, you never uses v3 from third loop anyway:

```
$.each(data, function(_, v1) {
  $.each(v1.user.products, function(_, v2) {
    let image = "";
    if (v2.image && v2.image.url) {
      image = v2.image.url;
    }
    $(".table").append($("<tr>").append(
      $("<img>").css({
        width: 60
      }).attr("src", image),
      $("<td>").addClass("Title").text(v2.title),
      $("<td>").addClass("Price").text("$" + v2.price),
      $("<td>").addClass("Stock").text(v2.stock),
      $("<td>").addClass("Link").append(
        $('<a target="_blank">').attr("href", "https://shop.link/product/" + v2.id + "/")
        .text("Buy Now"))
    ));
  });
});
```

EDIT:

I added logic to handle empty image value. Now it shows all users products.

Comment: The only time this fails is if `v2.image.url` doesn't exist (some cases in the JSON). So this would work if there's logic here to handle an empty `image` value

Comment: I appreciate the help, unfortunately this breaks the loop somehow and only shows the first set of data. When I added the v3 loop it fixed the issue for some reason. But this is defiantly the issue now that I did some further testing. Removing the  $.each(v2.image, function(_, v3) { fixes my issue but it breaks the image link and only shows the first user's data.

Comment: In which way image links break? The link is the same as in ```data``` so I don't see any errors.